# How to upgrade to Dart 2?

Tags: installation, dart, upgrade

In my macOS I need to install or upgrade to dart 2. But when I try I m getting this error. Any help please?

```
$ brew install dart
Warning: dart-lang/dart/dart 1.24.3 is already installed and up-to-date
To reinstall 1.24.3, run `brew reinstall dart`
$ brew install dart --devel
==> Installing dart from dart-lang/dart
Error: dart 1.24.3 is already installed
To upgrade to 2.0.0-dev.63.0, run `brew upgrade dart`
$ brew upgrade dart
Error: dart-lang/dart/dart 1.24.3 already installed
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an alternative to what Gunter suggested.

### Install Dart 2 without uninstalling Dart 1

```
> brew upgrade dart --devel --force
```

If you don't have Dart 1 installed, then simply use:

```
> brew install dart --devel
```

### Switching between Dart 1 and Dart 2

To switch to Dart 1, use the `switch` command followed by the version of Dart 1 that you have installed. For example:

```
> brew switch dart 1.24.3
```

Switching back to Dart 2 is similar, for example:

```
> brew switch dart 2.0.0-dev.64.1
```

### Listing Dart versions

If you aren't sure which versions of dart you have installed, then run `brew info`:

```
> brew info dart
dart-lang/dart/dart: stable 1.24.3, devel 2.0.0-dev.64.1
The Dart SDK
https://www.dartlang.org/
***[Your locally installed versions of dart will be listed here]***
```

### Using `dart@2` and `dart@1` formulas

Until Dart 2 final is released, you can use the brew formulas `dart@1` and `dart@2` as illustrated below.

**WARNING:** these formulas are **keg-only, which means installed binaries are not symlinked in the usual way**. Follow the instructions in the command output to set your PATH appropriately.

```
> brew install dart@2

==> Installing dart@2 from dart-lang/dart
==> Downloading https://storage.googleapis.com/dart-archive/channels/dev/release/2.0.0-dev.64.1/sdk/dartsdk-macos-x64-release.zip

######################################################################## 100.0%

==> Caveats

Note that this is a prerelease version of Dart.

Please note the path to the Dart SDK:

  /<your-brew-root-path>/opt/dart@2/libexec

This formula is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /...,
because this is an alternate version of another formula.

If you need to have this software first in your PATH run:

  echo 'export PATH="/<your-brew-root-path>/opt/dart@2/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: Thanks @Patrice this is what I am looking for.

Comment: I follow the instruction and upgrade to Dart 2. :)

Answer (score 2):

The warning text seems to be a bit unfortunate.

As far as I remember this worked for me

```
brew uninstall dart
# brew install dart --devel
brew install dart@2 # new
```

Answer (score 0):

```
brew uninstall dart
brew tap dart-lang/dart
brew install dart --devel
brew upgrade dart
```

you need `brew install dart --devel` since dart version  2 is still in beta and as such is only available on the developer channel.

Answer (score 0):

If you got 403 (forbidden) response

```
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 403
```

try this

You would have problem with switching on brew 2.6 and above. The brew switch command was removed after the 2.6 release of Homebrew [here](https://dart.dev/get-dart)

1. download sdk from source as mentioned [here](https://dart.dev/tools/sdk/archive#download-urls)
2. unzip at `/usr/local/Cellar/dart` and name extracted directory to sdk version: e.g 2.12.4/
3. change previous version directory name : e.g 2.8.4 -> dart-backup
   now you should have two directory : 2.12.4/ and dart-backup/
4. `brew unlink dart` to remove symlinks
5. `brew info dart` and make sure non of versions under **Conflicts with** are selected. (here you should see both 2.12.4 and dart-backup directories)
6. `brew link dart` and it will link to 2.12.4

These steps worked for me

Answer (score 0):

In the case, you install dart with flutter. Just need to run this command line:
flutter upgrade
Then flutter will upgrade the dart sdk too.