# How to install Dart, Dartium, Aqueduct on macOS High Sierra 10.13.5?

Tags: path, dart, macos-high-sierra, dartium, aqueduct

I have a Flutter Mobile App and I need to create a Restful API for my mobile app. I install WebStorm, I learn that I have to get Aqueduct framework etc.
I watch some video and try to google it some info to setup a environment in my macOS High Sierra. Because of I get all the information different places I am keep getting PATH issues. There is a lot of information about setting the environment on macOs High Sierra. So I need step by step guidance to set up my environment.

I have install IntelliJ and I have dart and fluter sdk plugin. Later I download and set to my Flutter SDK path to /Users/niyazitoros/flutter/ for my IntelliJ. Until today never had any problem. Now I need to do similar to my Dart SDK. **I used brew to install dart as;**

```
Last login: Fri Jun 22 13:38:50 on ttys000
Niyazis-MBP:~ niyazitoros$ brew info dart
dart-lang/dart/dart: stable 1.24.3, devel 2.0.0-dev.64.1
The Dart SDK
https://www.dartlang.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/dart/1.24.3 (2,807 files, 200.7MB) *
  Built from source on 2018-04-10 at 10:44:39
/usr/local/Cellar/dart/2.0.0-dev.64.1 (1,222 files, 372.9MB)
  Built from source on 2018-06-21 at 16:23:19
From: https://github.com/dart-lang/homebrew-dart/blob/master/dart.rb
==> Options
--with-content-shell
    Download and install content_shell -- headless Dartium for testing
--with-dartium
    Download and install Dartium -- Chromium with Dart
--devel
    Install development version 2.0.0-dev.64.1
==> Caveats
Please note the path to the Dart SDK:
  /usr/local/opt/dart/libexec
Niyazis-MBP:~ niyazitoros$
```

**My .bash_profil:**

```
#Setting PATH for flutter
PATH="/Users/niyazitoros/flutter/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

#Setting Dart2 Path
PATH="/user/local/opt/dart@2/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

#Setting Aqueduct
PATH="$PATH":"~/.pub-cache/bin"
export PATH
```

I want to clean everything and create a similar to flutter environment for dart. So here is list of my questions.

1. How to clean my both version of dart from macOS?
2. I create a users/niyazitoros/dart folder and I download Dart 1.24.3 
   and Dart 2.0.0-dev.64.1 both sdk inside this dart folder. For restful 
   api which version of dart sdk is best?
3. How to set the dart version to my path?
4. How to put aqueduct to my path?

I download and I will try to use WebStorm to build a restful api with aqueduct framework. So before my final question I also like to see the road I am trying to take is the correct one.

From the above questions(1-4) and the my goal of "**How to set an environment on macOS high Sierra, creating a Restful API for my Flutter Mobile App?**" can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dartium was only used in Dart 1 and is discontinued.

In Dart 2 use `pub run build_runner build` or `... serve`

Install Dart with

```
brew install dart@2
```

See also [How to upgrade to Dart 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50928834/how-to-upgrade-to-dart-2) for how to migrate from Dart 1 to Dart 2

Comment: Hi @Günter I see that. So, can you give me step by step info what is the best approch  setting an environment on macOS high Sierra, creating a Restful API for my Flutter Mobile App?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have that much time. That's a bit too broad for StackOverflow.