# How can I install and configure Dart 2 and Aqueduct on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, installation, dart, aqueduct

I have local network socket services. So, I need to deploy Aqueduct (on Ubuntu 18.04).

With Aqueduct, the my rest api backend it connects to my local network socket services (not a database) and front provides for me the REST API.

Whit this my Flutter Mobile App can connect to Aqueduct so I can get the information that I want. I guess the google cloud and docker file is not suitable for me. I am trying to give "LIFE" to old system using Aqueduct.

Everything works in my Mac Pro, but I am having difficulty to do the same using Ubuntu 18.04.

Where I can get "DETAIL" information to install Dart 2 and Aqueduct 3 on Ubuntu 18.04 and configure properly?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [How Do I Install Dart v2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49286161/how-do-i-install-dart-v2) for installing dart 2

From there you can follow along with the aqueduct install instructions

https://aqueduct.io/prerelease-3.0/docs/

But because we are deploying to production we won't use git. We download the tarball.

`wget https://github.com/stablekernel/aqueduct/archive/3.0.tar.gz
tar -xzf 3.0.tar.gz
cd aqueduct-3.0
pub global activate -spath aqueduct`